# How to access values by key in Twig without a for loop

Tags: php, twig

I am working with a datasource that is driven by GraphQL. It returns an array of key value pairs of parameters where the name of the parameter is the key. It is unfortunately set up as an array of objects. For example:

```
"parameters": [
  {
    "key": "property.domain",
    "value": "informium.net"
  },
  {
    "key": "facebooook.url",
    "value": "https://www.facebooook.com/informium"
  },
  {
    "key": "springoh.url",
    "value": "https://greenrivervalley.fffo.com/list-widget.js"
  },
  {
    "key": "guitar.applicationId",
    "value": "fHpJN0dfgdfrjjvE"
  },
  {
    "key": "property.phone",
    "value": "(707) 735-7311"
  }
]
```

Is there a way in PHP/Twig to access values by key without looping through this array every time I need to look something up? I would like to be able to get the value of a parameter by supplying only the key. For example:

`{% set propDomain = data.parameters["property.domain"] %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to pre-process the array in Twig using the merge() function like so:

```
{% set parametersHash = [] %}
{% for parameter in data.resolution.section.parameters %}
  {% set parametersHash = parametersHash|merge({(parameter.key): parameter.value}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

This allows me to access individual parameters by key like so:

`{{ parametersHash["guitar.applicationId"] }}`

which yields:

`fHpJN0dfgdfrjjvE`

Answer (score 0):

Not without preprocessing.

You can just preprocess the data to make it an associative array, along the lines of

```
$out_params = {};

foreach ($param in $parameters) {
  $key = $param["key"];
  $value = $param["value"];
  $out_params[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

You can then directly access the values using `out_params["my-key"]`.

This approach of course assumes that each key is unique. If it's not, the last value belonging to the key will appear in your flattened array.